# Angular 4 search box with duplicate text

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-forms, angular4-router

Angular 4 serach box issue

How to stop the value in second search box text when we enter value in one text box.
we have multiple searchbox for each of the item in my page.when we type any text in one search box the same value is getting binded to rest of all the search boxes. how to avoid this

```
<div class="search-container">
<div class="form-searchbox">
    <form>
          <input [(ngModel)]="studentSearchSvc.searchTerm"   
               #searchElement
               type="text"
               name="userSearch"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="studentName"
               autocomplete="off" />      
        <span class="search-icon" (click)="onButtonClick()"/> 
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3nqV.png)

Comment: Please can you post also other textbox code??

Comment: chances are you are binding same model to all text-boxes

Comment: If you are giving the same id-# to all your input elements you cannot expect a different result.

Comment: How to pass the id dynamically ? for each of the element

Comment: Share  full code of your template

Comment: As said, please post full code to help you. There is some ways how you can achieve the id dynamically, but without code we can not assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue from "[(ngModel)]" and "name" 
Try to give unique values for the individual input boxes

```
 <div class="search-container">
     <div class="form-searchbox">
      <form>
          <input [(ngModel)]="studentSearchSvc.searchTerm"   
               #searchElement1
               type="text"
               name="userSearch1"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="studentName"
               autocomplete="off" />      
        <span class="search-icon" (click)="onButtonClick()"/> 
      </form>
    </div>


    <div class="search-container">
     <div class="form-searchbox">
      <form>
          <input [(ngModel)]="studentSearchSvc.searchTerm2"   
               #searchElement2
               type="text"
               name="userSearch2"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="studentName"
               autocomplete="off" />      
        <span class="search-icon" (click)="onButtonClick()"/> 
      </form>
    </div>
```